# Sum Or Calculated Field in Dynamcis 365

Tags: dynamic, power-automate, dynamics-365, power-platform

I have a requirement where I need to create two fields on the order and show the total value based on following condition.

1. Value of New Orders = the total amount of orders for this customer, filtered to orders that have a Status Reason of New
2. Value of Open Orders = the total amount of orders for this customer, filtered to orders that have a status of New or Draft

Is it possible using SUM/Calculated field?

Comment: Can you provide more information?  i.e. what and where are you wanting to do this?  You've tagged PowerAutomate so I suspect there but what else can you show?  Far too hard to help at this stage unfortunately.

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at the concept of rollup fields: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/define-rollup-fields?view=op-9-1